# MDL with Angular2 components

Tags: angular, material-design-lite

I have created a sample Angular2 with MDL app. I am loading MDL js files in the footer. And I have created an Angular component which uses MDL text fields. On the very first request where there is no browser cache, all works as expected. But on page refresh (we got 304 for MDL js file), the text fields were not as expected. The labels are not moving and text field in not highlighting. How can i fix this problem? can we just avoid caching the js file (if yes, what is the best way to do this)? or any other way to do it?

Comment: Do you still have the issue? Did you consider to use a directive to upgrade your dynamic loaded components? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421919/integrating-material-design-lite-with-angular2