# Using Angular 2 with Material design lite

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

This has been asked in few of the previous posts. I am able to make it work in a certain way, but I am no able to make it work this way.

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421919/integrating-material-design-lite-with-angular2)

**MaterialDesignLiteUpgradeElement.ts**

```
import {Directive, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';
declare var componentHandler;

@Directive({
    selector: '[mdl]'
})
export class MDL {

    constructor() {
        componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
    }
}
```

**PrivateServersComponent.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {MDL} from '../../directives/MaterialDesignLiteUpgradeElement';

declare var componentHandler:any;
@Component({
    selector: 'private-server',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/private-server/privateServer.html',
    directives: [MDL],
    styleUrls: ['app/components/private-server/styles/private-server.css']
})
export class PrivateServersComponent{ 
constructor(private _privateServerService: PrivateServerService, el:ElementRef) {

        this.element =el;
    }
}
```

**privateServer.html**

```
<div mdl style="margin: auto; top:40px; position:relative; display:inline-block;">
<table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-shadow--2dp" id="list_private_servers">
    <thead align="">
    <tr>
        <th> Private Server IP</th>
        <th> Host ID</th>
        <th> Number of Video workers</th>
        <th> Number of PDF workers</th>
        <th> Switch </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="#privateServer of privateServers"> <!-- some logic based on my service
            <td>
                1
            </td>
            <td>
                2
            </td>
            <td>
                3
            </td>
            <td>
                  4
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="switch_public" class="material-icons" (click)="privateToPublic(privateServer.server_ip)">undo</div>
                <div class="mdl-tooltip  mdl-tooltip--large" for="switch_public">
                    <strong>Switch to Public Server</strong>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngIf="newEntry == 1">
            <td>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield millvi-half-width">
                    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="private_sever_ip" [(ngModel)]="newServer.ip">
                    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="private_sever_ip">IP</label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield millvi-half-width">
                    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" pattern="-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?" id="host_id" [(ngModel)]="newServer.id_host">
                    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for=host_id>Host ID</label>
                    <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Not a valid host id!</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield millvi-half-width">
                    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" pattern="-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?" id="video_workers" [(ngModel)]="newServer.video_workers">
                    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="video_workers">Video Workers</label>
                    <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Not Valid number of workers!</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield millvi-half-width">
                    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" pattern="-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?" id="pdf_workers" [(ngModel)]="newServer.pdf_workers">
                    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="pdf_workers">PDF Workers</label>
                    <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Not Valid number of workers!</span>
                </div>
            </td>

        </tr>

    </tbody>


</table>

</div>
```

The UI is not rendered properly. And I get the following error message

```
EXCEPTION: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'PrivateServersComponent'(PrivateServerService, undefined). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'PrivateServersComponent' is decorated with Injectable.
```

It works correctly without `directives:[mdl]` and adding a `componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered()`

## EDIT

I made changes to the constructor as the following

```
constructor(private _privateServerService: PrivateServerService) {
    }
```

and it works fine.

However, I get the following errors:

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: l is null
BrowserDomAdapter</BrowserDomAdapter.prototype.logError() angular2.dev.js:22911
BrowserDomAdapter</BrowserDomAdapter.prototype.logGroup() angular2.dev.js:22922
ExceptionHandler</ExceptionHandler.prototype.call() angular2.dev.js:1182
PlatformRef_</PlatformRef_.prototype._initApp/</<() angular2.dev.js:12562
NgZone</NgZone.prototype._notifyOnError() angular2.dev.js:13485
NgZone</NgZone.prototype._createInnerZone/errorHandling<.onError() angular2.dev.js:13389
u</e.prototype.run() angular2-polyfills.min.js:1
NgZone</NgZone.prototype._createInnerZone/<.$run/<() angular2.dev.js:13408
u</e.prototype.bind/<()
```

It works fine on initial loading, but when I switch tabs back to this one, it gives me this error.

I also tried to modify **MaterialDesignLiteUpgradeElement** as the following, but it doesn't work.

```
constructor(el:ElementRef) {
  componentHandler.upgradeElement(el.nativeElement);
}
```

Comment: Did you omit the constructor in `export class PrivateServersComponent{ 
}`? Does it have a constructor with two arguments? If so, please add the code to your question.

Comment: I added the constructor and changed it to solve the problem I mentioned, but I get some other error. Please check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

To not get an error when you also add `el:ElementRef` to the constructor, you need to import `ElementRef` into the file

```
import {Component, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';
```

Comment: I removed that part, since I don't need it. It works well now, but please check the edit part.

Comment: I guess this needs a Plunker with a full repo case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full working plunker of Angular2 + Material Design Lite's implementation of the Android.dot.com template, if this helps anyone.

[Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/DQPZyr/)