# Angular-Material to Material-Design-Light compatibility

Tags: angular, material-design, material-design-lite, angularjs-material

I have an `Angular-Material` app written obviously with `angularJS 1.x`

I want to rewrite that with `Angular 2`. Currently `Angular-Material2` is on really early stage so I just thinking would it be an easy way to somehow convert `Angular-Material` to `MDL`? How much of my current `Angular-Material` layouts and CSS code can I reuse?

Maybe someone had such experience and can give an advice?

Comment: Should work fine as long as you set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in all your components.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer A u able to provide a bit more details on that?

Comment: Sorry, no. Haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integrating Material Design Lite with Angular2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421919/integrating-material-design-lite-with-angular2)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer anyway thanks for tip. Looking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421919/integrating-material-design-lite-with-angular2/35159798 and here http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html atm

Comment: If you add the styles at index.html then `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` is not necessary.