# Execute directive when navigating to route component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

If I declare `component` inline I can execture directive on it

```
<stuff1-component my-directive></stuff1-component>
```

Is there any way to do something similar but in case of using `angular2` `component router`?

```
@RouteConfig([  
  { path: '/route1', name: 'Stuff1', component: Stuff2Component, directive: my-directive },
  { path: '/route2', name: 'Stuff2', component: Stuff2Component },
])
```

The reason I need to do that because I need to apply some behaivour to MDL component which I implemented as directive [Integrating Material Design Lite with Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421919/integrating-material-design-lite-with-angular2).

```
import {Directive, AfterViewInit} from 'angular2/core';
declare var componentHandler;

@Directive({
    selector: '[mdl]'
})    
export class MDL implements AfterViewInit {

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: what you want to do exactly pls exaplin bit more or post your code.

Comment: @micronyks  just updated the Q

Comment: to be clear, I really don't get the idea. But what I can feel is you may go with `host`. But still not sure. still wait someone else can guide you better !

Comment: @micronyks for each MDL component I need to call `componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();` so I have directive which does that. Inline I am doing `<my-component mdl></my-component>` - no problems at all, but in case of component routing I do not know how to do that.

Comment: Oh I see ! means what you want is, when a particular cmp becomes active, you want to run `componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();`, isn't it?

Comment: @micronyks Yes otherwise MDL components won't fully working. E.g table http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#tables-section wont display checkboxes, etc So I need to apply my directive that does `componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();`

Comment: Have you considered about using `viewchild api`? in a particular cmp, you can create an instance of your `custom directive` and with that you can call directive's code from a particular cmp with `ngAfterViewInit` hook

Comment: @micronyks haven't tried `viewchild`

Comment: @micronyks what this line is actulally doning `@ViewChild('selectedColorDirective') private vc:selectedColorDirective;` ?

Comment: @micronyks a u able to join back to discussion?