# MDL and Angular2 2.0.0-rc.1

Tags: angular, material-design-lite

I am struggling in getting Material Design Lite (MDL) to work with the 2.0.0-rc.1 version of Angular2, specifically with dynamic content.

I have two components, one being the main app component that incorporates the second. I can put HTML into the main component's template, use MDL classes, have the component `implement OnInit`  and call `componentHandler.upgradeDom()` from there. All HTML added thus far is now registered by MDL.

However when I have the second component use a `service` and dynamically add the result into its template, then this stuff is not registered by the first `componentHandler.upgradeDom()`. I don't understand why calling `componentHandler.upgradeDom()` from the second component after it has added the dynamic content does not work, either. I thought it should. Does it use a different `componentHandler` or something?

Another idea would be to have the 2nd component somehow call a function of the first component to tell it to use its `componentHandler` and update the DOM from there, but I don't know how to do that.

For test purposes I added a native Javascript file that calls the very same and have a button trigger it - that works.

I have found several directives on StackOverflow that supposedly auto-register all new HTML, but none work for me. Does anyone know how to do this for this version of Angular2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately theUtherSide's answer didn't work me, either.

My mistake was very specific to my project. I was adding dynamic content and telling `componentHandler.upgradeDom();` but it didn't work for content that was **not visible** at that moment due to CSS setting it to `opacity: 0; max-height: 0`. This is correct for my project, which would change those settings upon a click to make them visible to the user. Apparently this is why it was ignored for the `upgradeDom()` function.

I have added the same function elsewhere in my code - basically when I load the content I set a boolean to true indicating that it has changed. When the user makes visible such a hidden part and that boolean is true, then the function is called and the boolean set to false so it doesn't happen every time.

Maybe someone else is in the same spot. It's certainly not the nicest solution, having to check for these things and whatnot, but hey, it works.

**Edit**
Actually I'm not 100% positive it was because the content in question was *hidden*, maybe I was just calling the function *too early*. Might want to check for that, too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the directive found here to call `componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();` :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35451821/1341825

In order to get component CSS to work, you also need to set `encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None` on your component (do `import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';`)

You may also need to inject an `ElementRef` into the component and then explicitly call `componentHandler.upgradeElement` on it.  (This did not work for me, but I saw it working in some examples.)  Checkout:

- https://gist.github.com/tbassetto/fa36518660cfcc7e0b62
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35217588/1341825.