# Material Design Light + Angular 2

Tags: angular, material-design-lite

Anyone know why in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/Wntce9) the Material Design Lite sidenav (or drawer as they call it) won't display when used as a component?

It works fine when it's not used as a component like in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/DQPZyr)

I'm using the following but maybe in the wrong area????

```
componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling with this as well.  I have the the component mostly working, but it does not dismiss the drawer when I click the content.

I found this helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35451821/1341825

Try adding the `mdl` attribute to your root node. Like:

`<div mdl class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">`

Comment: I also use this in my applciation.

Comment: I looked at the link you provided and also tried the custom directive they talked about using `componentHandler.upgradeElement(el.nativeElement);` but it still didn't work.

Comment: By the way, i think i had the same issue you are describing where the drawer wouldn't close before i fixed the CSS issue.  You have to use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in each of your components, otherwise the css rules are blocked out by default.

Comment: Like i said though, i can get the drawer to work (and I provided an example) if i leave the drawer in the original html of the entire page, but if i break it off into it's own component, that's when it breaks.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `encapsulation`. It didn't solve the issue with the drawer....will keep trying and report back here.

Comment: Turns out i had mis-matched versions in my references to the MDL CSS and JS.  Doh.  All working now.  Setting `ViewEncapsulation.None` made my CSS work at the component level too.  I'm using the directive as-described in the link in my answer.

In your non-working example, I think the drawer needs to be included in the same template as the header.  I was not able to break it out into a partial, even when I nest the partial within `<div mdl class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be done using Material Design Lite, at least not now.  I ended up using Angular Material 2 and was able to separate the sidenav into it's own component.  View [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/NPRjKx) for an example.

Following is the code in case the link doesn't work.

app.component.html

```
<my-sidenav></my-sidenav>
```

app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {SidenavComponent} from 'sidenav.component.ts';
import {GlueService} from 'glue.service.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'material-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  directives: [SidenavComponent],
  providers: [GlueService]
})
export class AppComponent {
}

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Since the sidenav is an outside container to everything else it has to be loaded first:

sidenav.component.html

```
<md-sidenav-layout>
<md-sidenav #start [opened]="opened" id="left_sidenav" layout-padding>
<h2>Sidenav</h2>
<button md-raised-button class="md-raised md-primary" (click)="start.close()">Close</button>
</md-sidenav>
<md-content>
<my-content></my-content>
</md-content>
</md-sidenav-layout>
```

sidenav.component.ts

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MdButton} from '@angular2-material/button';
import {MD_SIDENAV_DIRECTIVES, MdSidenav} from '@angular2-material/sidenav';
import {ContentComponent} from 'content.component.ts';
import {GlueService} from 'glue.service.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-sidenav',
  templateUrl: 'sidenav.component.html',
  directives: [MdButton, MD_SIDENAV_DIRECTIVES, ContentComponent],
  providers: []
})
export class SidenavComponent{
opened: false;
@ViewChild('start') sidenavComponent: MdSidenav;
constructor(private glueService: GlueService) {

glueService.toggleConfirmed$.subscribe(
  toggle => {
    this.toggleLeftNav();
  });
}
toggleLeftNav(){

 (<MdSidenav>this.sidenavComponent).open();

}

}
```

The content component contains the header and the content.  You could easily split this up into 2 components.

content.component.html

```
<md-toolbar color="primary">
<button md-raised-button style="color:black;margin:10px" (click)="openLeftNav()">Open Sidenav</button>
Angular Material 2 App
</md-toolbar>
<h2>Content</h2>
```

content.component.ts

```
import {Component,  OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import {MdToolbar} from '@angular2-material/toolbar';
import {MdButton} from '@angular2-material/button';
import { GlueService } from 'glue.service.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-content',
  templateUrl: 'content.component.html',
  directives: [MdToolbar, MdButton]
})
export class ContentComponent implements OnDestroy{
   constructor(private glueService: GlueService) { }

   openLeftNav(){
     this.glueService.confirmToggle(true);
   }

}
```

I created a service (no idea what to call it) that allows the different components to talk to each other.  I called it glue.service.ts.  I also don't know if this is the BEST way for one component to talk to another although this method was mentioned in Angular 2's cookbook.

glue.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';
@Injectable()
export class GlueService {
  private toggleAnnouncedSource = new Subject<boolean>();
  private toggleConfirmedSource = new Subject<boolean>();
  // Observable string streams
  toggleAnnounced$ = this.toggleAnnouncedSource.asObservable();
  toggleConfirmed$ = this.toggleConfirmedSource.asObservable();
  // Service message commands
  announceToggle(toggle: boolean) {
    this.toggleAnnouncedSource.next(toggle)
  }
  confirmToggle(toggle: boolean) {
    this.toggleConfirmedSource.next(toggle);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you had a look to my answer? I would not say this is not possible with **Material Design Lite**.  But  Angular Material 2   will probably be easier to use with Angular.

Comment: I agree, Material 2 is easier, when you start doing things like *ngIf you'll wish you were using MD2 instead of MDL.

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem in your MDL drawer as Angular component is, that `mdl-layout__drawer` needs to be a direct child of `mt mdl-js-layout`.
But in your "generated" html the `<my-sidenav>`is still the parent of  `mdl-layout__drawer`

```
  <div data-upgraded=",MaterialLayout" class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header is-small-screen is-upgraded">
    <div class="android-header mdl-layout__header mdl-layout__header--waterfall">..</div>
     <my-sidenav>   
       <div class="android-drawer mdl-layout__drawer">
        <nav class="mdl-navigation">
          <a href="" class="mdl-navigation__link">Nav 1</a>
        </nav>
       </div>
      </my-sidenav>
      <div mdl="" class="android-content mdl-layout__content">
        <h2>Content stuff here</h2>...
      </div>
  </div
```

To avoid that you may change your component to **Attribute directive**.

```
@Component({
    selector: '[my-sidenav]',
    ...
```

And use it like this:

```
<div my-sidenav class="android-drawer mdl-layout__drawer"></div>
```

Have a look to the changed [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ajVro5C2BPs9wEig7a9R)