# Angular 2 Error ( 'directives' does not exist in type 'Component' )

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, components

I am beginner in Angular 2 and I'm using the final Angular 2 release version. I have a strange problem with it.
this is my **databinding.component.ts** code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import {PropertyBindingComponent} from './property-binding.component';
import {EventBindingComponent} from './event-binding.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'fa-databinding',
  templateUrl: 'databinding.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['databinding.component.css'],
  directives: [PropertyBindingComponent, EventBindingComponent]
})
```

and this is a peace of my **app.module.ts** code :

```
import { PropertyBindingComponent } from './databinding/property-binding.component';
import { EventBindingComponent } from './databinding/event-binding.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    OtherComponent,
    AnotherComponent,
    DatabindingComponent,
    PropertyBindingComponent,
    EventBindingComponent
  ]
```

This code does not work correctly:

```
ERROR in [default] /home/tornado/work/first-app/src/app/databinding/databinding.component.ts:11:2 
Argument of type '{ selector: string; template: any; styles: any[]; directives: (typeof PropertyBindingComponent | ...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'directives' does not exist in type 'Component'.
```

What should I do?!?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 version RC.6 "directives" inside @Component Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410591/angular2-version-rc-6-directives-inside-component-error)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`directives` was removed from component.
See the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39410642/5487673

The solution to the problem is simply to remove the `directives` attribute from your component. So long as the components listed under your `directives` attribute are declared at the `NgModule` level then you should be right.

Comment: If you find this answer helpful accept it by clicking on the ✓ tick button.

Comment: I have the same for 'bindings', maybe provide the alternative instead of leaving us empty-handed.

Comment: There is no alternative, you just remove 'directives' from your component. As long as you've declared the 'directive' component in your module then you're good to go. Updated the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered that case and solved.
As directives, you don't need to import and plug them to specific component. 
You could use them like this.

First, import them on the app.module.ts.
Second, add imported directive into declarations.
Then they would be working.